# .htaccess to rewrite URL's with parameter

Tags: html, .htaccess

I wish to change my URL's from example this:

```
www.website.com/?page=about
www.website.com/?page=info
www.website.com/?page=contact
```

to this:

```
www.website.com/about
www.website.com/info
www.website.com/contact
```

This should be doable with one rule I hope. I've been looking around but I see people doing each occurrence separately.
So the only URL parameter is "page" and the website has only one depth. Should be easy right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic common question. This goes in the .htaccess in your root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#prevent anyone from using the old urls
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /+\?page=([^&\ ]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

#provide pretty URL's
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm curious: is there any particular reason you tend to use `THE_REQUEST` as opposed to `QUERY_STRING`? After all, the query string is all that needs to be tested here... I just think that, for those who are new to mod_rewrite, this may look a tad confusing, especially since not many know what `THE_REQUEST` normally contains...

Comment: Using `QUERY_STRING` will cause redirect loop since `QUERY_STRING` get rewritten to `?page=...` in 2nd rule. `THE_REQUEST` doesn't change its value after execution of other rules.

Comment: Of course - and there I've been using dummy `&r`s to prevent the loop. That makes much more sense - thanks for clarifying.